# Reshaping Pandas Dataframe: Unique Column values as Column names

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe representing a one-to-many tag relationships, with column names 'user_id' and 'tags'. A user_id can be associated with many tags, but I want to rearrange my dataframe such that there is only one user_id per row and each tag value is its own column.

i.e. I have:

```
User_id, Tags

1, Dresses,    
1, Accessories,
2, Dresses,
2, Hats,
```

AND WANT:

```
User_id, Dresses, Accessories, Hats,    
1,        1,         1,         0,
2,        1,          0,         1,
```

OR

```
User_id, Dresses, Accessories, Hats,
1,        True,         True,         False,    
2,        True,          False,         True,
```

Comment: Take a look at pandas' pivot()

Answer (score 0):

you can use `get_dummies` and `groupby`:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,1,2,2],'tags':['Dresses','Accessories','Dresses','Hats']})
pd.get_dummies(df).groupby('user_id').max()
```

returns:

```
       tags_Accessories     tags_Dresses    tags_Hats
user_id             
1       1                   1                0
2       0                   1                1
```